# What does assembly: directive/attribute do?

Tags: c#, attributes

What does [assembly: mean? 
What does the compiler/linker do when it sees this attribute?
I googled this feature but couldn't find any answer to it.

Comment: Did you google well? [Setting Assembly Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4w8c1y2s.aspx)

Comment: It is not a directive, it is an attribute.

Comment: @WiktorZychla: Actually, it's an attribute modifier.

Comment: @BenVoigt: correct, thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is [MSDN Assembly Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4w8c1y2s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) reference.

Assembly attributes are values that provide information about an assembly. The attributes are divided into the following sets of information:

1. Assembly identity attributes.
2. Informational attributes.
3. Assembly manifest attributes.
4. Strong name attributes.

Whereas [Assembly Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.aspx) represents an assembly, which is a reusable, versionable, and self-describing building block of a common language runtime application.